# Configure access another website in iis externally

Tags: dns, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have a server on private cloud with installed IIS.
Under IIS Default Web Site I have websites and I added another site.
Default Web Site have http 80 and https 443 bindings.
On the other site I defined https 1443 binding.

Under our domain we have a sub domain that in the DNS refers to the IP of the cloud.
So if I go to the subdomain URL a have an access to all the sites that appears under Default Web Site.

How can I configure that if I go to subdomain url/NewWebSite it will forward in to port 1443 and access the NewWebSite in IIS ?

I have found URL Rewrite option but i don't know what address to put in the rule for rewrite/redirect ?

Comment: DNS won't be able to redirect to port 1443. URL Rewrite alone won't help either. You need to set up a reverse proxy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: I am trying but can't figure out how to write the rules if it is on the same server and the site is a react app so I don't have default.aspx page.

Comment: I set the bindings of the new website to the same port as default website (443) and added a host name.
It is working within localhost but externally if i write the subdomain/hostname  I receive 404 - File or directory not found. Why it can't figure out this address ?

Comment: Don't you know how to create suitable url rewrite rules? If so, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module). there are many reasons for the 404 error, you need more information to analyze this error, such as failed request tracking.

Comment: I did write an URL rewrite rule but when is served I receive a blank page and its source it is the source of my index.html but all the references are like '/static/.' 
its not loading the static resources right. Its exactly like I add the build folder as Application in Default Web Site

Comment: I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.